# Facebook Graph API 2.5 - unable to access friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm simply trying to display list of friends of logged in user.  I understand that the app will only show friends that both have given access to the app.

My problem I'm finding is that my response data object returns an empty array.

When I make a call to /v.2.5/me/permissions it correctly displays my permissions of:

```
{ data: [{ permission: 'email', status: 'granted' },
 { permission: 'public_profile', status: 'granted' } ] }
```

I can see that the user_friends permission is not there.  In the settings of my App in the back end of FB, it clearly shows email, public_profile and users_friends as approved permissions.

Does anyone know why users_friends permission is not being allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the settings of my App in the back end of FB, it clearly shows email, public_profile and users_friends as approved permissions.

“Approved” means that your app *can* ask a user for a permission – but it does of course *not* mean that the user automatically *grants* that permission to your app.

You have to ask for `user_friends` permission the same way you ask for any other – by passing it to the login dialog via the `scope` parameter.